# BorderLands 2 VS BorderLands 1

Tags: borderlands-2, borderlands, framerate

So I've tried playing borderlands expectant of seeing massive drops in fps at the lowest possible settings seeing as how I'm playing on an integrated 256mb amd GPU.

Its a notebook so I'm in a tight pinch.

Now I know overall in gameplay BL2 is much more saturated.

But is BL2 more optimized?

I receive an avg fps of about 24, min: 12, max: 32 in border lands 1.

Could I hope to receive a steady 30 in BL2?

I can play CS source at almost max settings with ample 30 fps breathing room, but borderlands 1 doesn't even offer that at its lowest settings.

I googled the question, it doesn't exist.

TL;DR: Is BL2 more optimized than BL1?

Comment: You have an integrated GPU; do you meet the system requirements for the game?

Comment: @Frank At minimum, yes

Comment: Then your best bet is to try it and see; that's the whole point of system requirements.

Comment: nope, BL 1 is "lighter" .

Comment: @NamikazeSheena Darn

Comment: @DerpyLeSquid ,maybe you can try messing with "WillowEngine.ini" in My Documents. or just look [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands2/comments/1xq0e1/ultra_low_graphics_settings_ini_file/)

Comment: @DerpyLeSquid that if you prefer smooth gameplay rather than great graphics

Comment: @NamikazeSheena Been there done that, made a 4 fps difference just about, thanks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on more things than on the amount of MB. Some GPU have different algorithms implemented to calculate for example shaders.

If you set the Options to max, Borderlands 2 has the higher values. On minimum I don't know. But another important thing is, that Borderlands 2 has bigger and more maps, more weapon models, more skins, more everything... So it's also a reason of CPU and RAM. Without the other options, it is hard to tell. But usually it should run worse dan BL1. It also may differ on each map you're in.